# regression line with a factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R to do an analysis of the `mtcars` data set and I was surprised when I couldn't add a regression line for a factor variable with `ggplot2`. Specifically the following code takes the automatic transmission column `am` and creates an additional column of type, factor.

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$automaticTransmission <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
levels(mtcars$automaticTransmission) <- c('automatic', 'manual')
```

The name of the new column is `manualTransmission` and when I run the following code:

```
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars)
g <- g + geom_point() + aes(x=automaticTransmission, y=mpg)
g <- g + geom_smooth(method=lm)
g
```

`geom_smooth` fails to produce a regression line in my plot. However, if I use the original `am` column, then it's there:

```
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars)
g <- g + geom_point() + aes(x=am, y=mpg)
g <- g + geom_smooth(method=lm)
g
```

Can anyone tell me why this is? I'm guessing it has less to do with R/ggplot2 and more with misunderstanding something more fundamental, but I'm just learning statistics, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: I don't think that regression line is very useful to begin with...

Comment: ggplot2 uses the `predict` function to get values for plotting. However, it is no possible to predict between factor values (by definition there is no "between").